# Git repository on NFS/Samba

Tags: git, samba, nfs

Are there any thing to worry if my Git repository is on NFS/Samba?

E.g. file locking in NFS is not reliable, so it will affect the Git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there's only one person accessing the repository, you'll be fine. Don't share a repository among users that way. Your data will be safe, but simultaneous pushes might conflict on what ends up at the HEAD of each branch.

Answer (score 2):

Placing git repository on samba can produce issues with file permissions (especially +x) as samba does not store them but git does.

Comment: This is only true if the server or client are on Windows. Using the CIFS support in the Linux kernel and Samba, you should get proper support for file modes.

Comment: But why would you use samba in the first place if the client are not Windows machines?